# Remove description from list in RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net

I have a list of accounts in a RichTextBox:

```
username:password|description
username1:password1|description
username3:password3|description3
username4:password5|description6
username1:password3|description5
username2:password4|description5
username2:password3|description3
```

The amount of rows in the list is arbitrary.

I want to remove the `"|description"` part of each row. Any suggestions?

Comment: How to you populate the list? I'm sure you could remove it right before the data is inserted in the list.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: grammar, adding a question

Answer (score 0):

Use a Regex

```
Dim rx As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\|(.+)")
RichTextBox1.Text = rx.Replace(RichTextBox1.Text, "")
```

This will remove any number of characters beginning with and including the pipe `|`. It will work with a RichTextBox having a Text property of any length (any number of rows).

If you want to leave just the password, you can do two replaces

```
Dim rx As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\|(.+)")
RichTextBox1.Text = rx.Replace(RichTextBox1.Text, "")
rx = New Regex("(.+):")
RichTextBox1.Text = rx.Replace(RichTextBox1.Text, "")
```

Just remove anything up to and including the `:`

And just in case you ask, you could also remove the password with this

```
Dim rx As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(":(.+)\|")
RichTextBox1.Text = rx.Replace(RichTextBox1.Text, "|") ' or replace with ":"
```

Without regex?

```
Dim lines = RichTextBox1.Text.Split(vbLf)
Dim elements = lines.Select(Function(line) line.Split({":"c, "|"c}))
' password
RichTextBox1.Text = String.Join(vbLf, elements.Select(Function(element) element(1)))
' username:password
RichTextBox1.Text = String.Join(vbLf, elements.Select(Function(element) element(0) & ":" & element(1)))
' you get the idea
```

Comment: the description is not "description" , its random text , example , john:12345|premium  , and its unknown lines amount , can be 1000

Comment: Anyway, you can use the new one I just edited my answer with

Comment: Lotus had a good comment to your question. If you can, don't print the description at all in the first place.

Comment: without the username and without the desk

Answer (score 0):

Spilt the text into an array then rewrite the items in the array to the text box

```
 Dim arr1() As String=Split (rtb.Text,VbLf)
 Dim finalstring As String= ""
 For x As Integer=0 to Ubound(arr1) - 1
    Dim arr2 () As String = Split (arr1 (x), "|")
    finalstring += arr2 (0) & vbNewLine
 Next
 rtb.Text=  finalstring
```

to show just the password;  use the same technique as above

```
 Dim arr1() As String=Split(rtb.Text,VbLf)
 Dim finalstring As String= ""
 For x As Integer = 0 to Ubound(arr1) - 1
    Dim arr2 () As String = Split (arr1 (x), "|")
          For x As Integer=0 to Ubound(arr2) - 1        
                   Dim arr3 () As String = Split (arr2 (0), ":")
                   finalstring += arr3 (1) & vbNewLine
      Next
 Next
 rtb.Text=  finalstring
```

Comment: thank you , and how can i see just the password? remove the username and the desk using : and |